# Faster way of looping through rows of matrix

Tags: r

I have a matrix of the following for:-

```
matA <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0,
                 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
                 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
                 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1,
                 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
               nrow = 6, ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
```

The actual matrix is quite large (please keep that in mind).

And I have a list of the following form

```
listA <- list(c(2, 3, 6), c(1, 4, 5), c(1, 5), c(2, 6), c(2, 3, 6), c(1, 4, 5))
```

Now, the `listA` specifies the locations of `1`'s in the matrix. And I transform this matrix into a row standardized form in the following manner:-

```
rowsumz <- unlist(lapply(listA, length))

for(i in 1:nrow(matA)){
  matA[i, listA[[i]]] <- matA[i, listA[[i]]]/rowsumz[i]
}
```

Is there a faster way doing this????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try

```
matA / rowSums(matA)
```

or

```
matA / lengths(listA)
```

and you will obtain

```
          [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]
[1,] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333
[2,] 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
[3,] 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000
[4,] 0.0000000 0.5000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.5000000
[5,] 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333
[6,] 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
```